# Avoid empty spaces in vue-form-generator inputs

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the schema-based form generator component for Vue.js ([vue-form-generator](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator))

Does anyone knows how to avoid dynamically empty spaces in the input field by using the `trim()` function?

[Here is an example of the code.](https://codepen.io/aruizh/pen/VweZqjv)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#trim

Comment: @Phil I think this way is not possible to use with the vue-form-generator component. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `validator` method by this:

```
validator: function(value, field, model) {
    if (value) {
        // if user input anything, then trim it and assign it to the model and validator value also.
        // this could be devastating as the user will fill difficulties in typing space
        // because as long as user type a space to write a separate word, the validator will remove this, test properly 
        value = model.name = value.trim();
        return VueFormGenerator.validators.string(value, field, model)
    } else {
        return ["This field is required"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if this is what I need.I want to erase the spaces while the user is typing.

Comment: @AlbertoRhuertas when do you want to erase spaces, after submitting or as soon as user types it?

Comment: As soon as the user types it. At this moment I'm trying this on the `onChanged` method: `newVal = newVal.replace(/ /g, "")` but I need to erase the spaces visually too.

Comment: @AlbertoRhuertas I've updated my code according to your need. Check the code now. But one important thing, this could be devastating as the user will fill difficulties in typing space because as long as user type a space to write a separate word, the validator will remove this, test properly